# Having trouble understand the small details of Inheritance in Java

Tags: java

I was learning about Inheritance of classes in Java, and I have trouble understanding how it works.

For example, consider this:

```
class SalesPerson {
    public void sale() {
        System.out.print("greet ");
        pitch();
    }
    
    public void pitch() {
        System.out.print("pitch ");
    }
}

class CommissionedSalesPerson extends SalesPerson {
    public void sale() {
        super.sale();
        System.out.print("record ");
    }
    
    public void pitch() {
        super.pitch();
        System.out.print("close ");
    }
}
```

When I do

```
    SalesPerson Vincent = new CommissionedSalesPerson();
    Vincent.sale();
```

I expect the output to be `greet pitch record`, however, we get `greet pitch close record`. So I thought that maybe super classes method, unless mentioned with `this` use the sub-class method. But, adding to the confusion, when I did this:

```
class SalesPerson {
    private String PitchString = "Hello! ";
    
    public void sale() {
        System.out.print("greet ");
        System.out.print(PitchString);
    }
    
    public void pitch() {
        System.out.print("Pitch ");
    }
}

class CommissionedSalesPerson extends SalesPerson {
    private String PitchString = "Commissioned Hello! ";
    
    public void sale() {
        super.sale();
        System.out.print("record ");
    }
    
    public void pitch() {
        super.pitch();
        System.out.print("close ");
    }
}
```

I expect (similar to above)

```
greet Commissioned Hello! record
```

but got

```
greet Hello! record
```

I'd appreciate if someone could explain how methods are called in Class Inheritance in Java and why are they called like that (so I don't have to memorize and forget later).

Comment: You're experiencing the differences between dynamic binding (when calling the methods) and static binding (when referring to `PitchString`). Enjoy finding more about those terms with your favorite search engines!

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Method calls are dynamically dispatched, field accesses are statically bound. Methods can be overridden, fields cannot be (they can only be shadowed).

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you very much. I'll learn about it.